# Linq to SQL query taking forever

Tags: sql, linq, translation

Ok, first I thought I had a problem with how I was querying things. But apparently the problem lies in how linq translates my query to sql.

Here's my linq:

```
var items = (from p in ctx.bam_Prestatie_AllInstances
             join q in ctx.bam_Zending_AllRelationships on p.ActivityID equals q.ReferenceData
             join r in ctx.bam_Zending_AllInstances on q.ActivityID equals r.ActivityID
             orderby p.LastModified descending
             where r.PrestatieOntvangen >= vanaf && r.PrestatieOntvangen <= tm
             select new Data.BAMPrestatieInstance
               {
                Aanvaard = p.PrestatieAanvaard,
                Contactnummer = r.ContactNr,
                Identificatie = p.Identificatie,
                Foutmelding = ((p.Foutmelding == "" || p.Foutmelding == null) && p.PrestatieAanvaard == null) ? "De prestatie is bezig met verwerkt te worden." : p.Foutmelding.Replace("\r\n", " "),
                Ontvangen = p.PrestatieZendingOntvangen,
                Uitvoerdatum = p.Uitvoerdatum.Replace('-', '/'),
                Zender = r.Zender,
                PrestatieCode = p.PrestatieCode,
                ZendingsNr = r.Zendingnummer.ToString(),
                GroepsAanvaarding = r.Identificatie
               }).Take(100);
```

Which gets translated in:

```
SELECT TOP (100) [t3].[Zender], [t3].[ContactNr] AS [Contactnummer], [t3].[Identificatie], [t3].[value] AS [Uitvoerdatum], [t3].[PrestatieZendingOntvangen] AS [Ontvangen], [t3].[PrestatieAanvaard] AS [Aanvaard], [t3].[value2] AS [Foutmelding], [t3].[PrestatieCode], [t3].[value3] AS [ZendingsNr], [t3].[Identificatie2] AS [GroepsAanvaarding]

FROM (

    SELECT [t2].[Zender], [t2].[ContactNr], [t0].[Identificatie], REPLACE([t0].[Uitvoerdatum], @p0, @p1) AS [value], [t0].[PrestatieZendingOntvangen], [t0].[PrestatieAanvaard], 

        (CASE 

            WHEN (([t0].[Foutmelding] = @p2) OR ([t0].[Foutmelding] IS NULL)) AND ([t0].[PrestatieAanvaard] IS NULL) THEN CONVERT(NVarChar(3800),@p3)

            ELSE REPLACE([t0].[Foutmelding], @p4, @p5)

         END) AS [value2], [t0].[PrestatieCode], CONVERT(NVarChar,[t2].[Zendingnummer]) AS [value3], [t2].[Identificatie] AS [Identificatie2], [t2].[PrestatieOntvangen], [t0].[LastModified]

    FROM [dbo].[bam_Prestatie_AllInstances] AS [t0]

    INNER JOIN [dbo].[bam_Zending_AllRelationships] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ActivityID] = [t1].[ReferenceData]

    INNER JOIN [dbo].[bam_Zending_AllInstances] AS [t2] ON [t1].[ActivityID] = [t2].[ActivityID]

    ) AS [t3]

WHERE ([t3].[PrestatieOntvangen] >= @p6) AND ([t3].[PrestatieOntvangen] <= @p7)

ORDER BY [t3].[LastModified] DESC
```

As you can see, first it selects EVERYTHING and then it takes the top 100 and does the where. Why is this? Why can't it directly do the top 100, I think the problem why my queries run so long is because of this. Is there a better way to construct my linq query then?

Thanks

Comment: Funny thing I noticed btw, if i REMOVE the TOP 100 from the query it takes 4 seconds and shows me 22000 items, if i set the top 100 back again, it takes 55seconds. I think it has something to do with copying it to a temporary table or something

Comment: I temporarily fixed my problem by just selecting all and looping through the first 100 lines, it goes a lot faster but I'm not that pleased :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var items =  from p in ctx.bam_Prestatie_AllInstances.OrderByDesc(p => p.LastModified).Take(100) 
             join q in ctx.bam_Zending_AllRelationships on p.ActivityID equals q.ReferenceData 
             join r in ctx.bam_Zending_AllInstances on q.ActivityID equals r.ActivityID 
             where r.PrestatieOntvangen >= vanaf && r.PrestatieOntvangen <= tm 
             select new Data.BAMPrestatieInstance 
               { 
                Aanvaard = p.PrestatieAanvaard, 
                Contactnummer = r.ContactNr, 
                Identificatie = p.Identificatie, 
                Foutmelding = ((p.Foutmelding == "" || p.Foutmelding == null) && p.PrestatieAanvaard == null) ? "De prestatie is bezig met verwerkt te worden." : p.Foutmelding.Replace("\r\n", " "), 
                Ontvangen = p.PrestatieZendingOntvangen, 
                Uitvoerdatum = p.Uitvoerdatum.Replace('-', '/'), 
                Zender = r.Zender, 
                PrestatieCode = p.PrestatieCode, 
                ZendingsNr = r.Zendingnummer.ToString(), 
                GroepsAanvaarding = r.Identificatie 
               };
```

Since the sort applies only to your first table, I'd try to force the order by and take 100 to be applied before the join.

Comment: Tried this btw, went a bit faster, but my alternative solutions was still better. But also not good enough :(

Comment: It sure seems so. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857807/linq-to-sql-take-w-o-skip-causes-multiple-sql-statements/869340#869340 for an explanation why LINQ to SQL creates a sub-query that it then TOPs.

Comment: @WtFudgE, noting your comments here and in the question, all I can say is that sometimes LINQ isn't the best answer. Code generation doesn't necessarily lead to optimized code. If you still want to use LINQ (and I certainly would want to), you might consider coding the join as a view in the database, then using LINQ to query the view.