# Does LINQ skip & take have decent performance?

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, ado.net, skip-take

We have a query for about 40 data fields related to customers.  The query will often return a large amount of records, say up to 20,000.  We only want to use say around the first 500 results.  Then, we just want to be able to page through them 10 at a time.

Is LINQ skip and take a reasonable approach for this?  Are there any potentnialy performance issues with using this approach vs doing it manually some other way?

Comment: not if you do it correctly. best way is to code it, then actually see what query is being executed, and compare that to what you would write if you had to write the raw sql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Take()` without `Skip()` generates SQL using `TOP` clause.

`Take()` with `Skip` generates SQL using `ROW_NUMBER()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857807/linq-to-sql-take-w-o-skip-causes-multiple-sql-statements).

Also, I'd recommend to use excellent [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) tool or LINQ to SQL logging to check generated queries.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you're on SQL Server 2005+ it'll generate SQL that uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to make paging efficient (not unlike the SQL that [Scott uses in this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/01/434314.aspx)).